# One who doesn't try very hard

Tags: single-word-requests

is there a word to describe one who doesn't try very hard? not someone who doesn't try at all, but one who does their work without much enthusiasm or perhaps with as much gusto as others.

Answer (score 1):

I would immediately suggest [***slacker***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20slacker&oq=define%20slacker)

> a person who avoids work or effort

This person might also be described as [***half-hearted***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20half-hearted&oq=define%20half-hearted)

> without enthusiasm or energy

Answer (score 1):

A word with particularly bad personal connotations is "**underachiever**"

Per Weather Vane, from Cambridge again:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/underachiever

underachiever  noun [ C ] us ​ /ˌʌn·dər·əˈtʃi·vər/

a person whose performance is lower than you would expect, based on that person's ability

Answer (score 0):

Someone might make *lacklustre* efforts.

The [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lacklustre) gives the example

> Britain's number-one tennis player gave a disappointingly lacklustre
>   performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a neat, obsolete word, I just learned of *slugabed*, meaning

> a lazy person who stays in bed late

It's not a precise word for your definition, but it's a colorful that gets across a similar idea. A slugabed most likely doesn't work hard either.